# React prop array length returning 0

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array prop on a component called jobs that will show in the console, but always returns length:0

[image: console.log screenshot]

The Image you will see definitely has three elements in the array, but when I attempt to access the array length through console.log(this.props.jobs.length);

Why do the elements of this array log out, but I can't access the elements in code?

Per request from @finalfreq, see full code below:

```
const DepartmentContainer = React.createClass({
   getInitialState:function(){
     return{sortedJobs:{}, loaded:false};
   },
   componentDidMount:function(){
     //console.log(this.state.sortedJobs);
     var departments = this.props.departments;
     departments.map(function(name, index){
       this.state.sortedJobs[name] = [];
     }, this)

     var _this = this;

     axios.get('{api call returning json}')
     .then(function (response) {
       for(let i=0;i<response.data.jobs.length;i++){
         for(let j=0;j<response.data.jobs[i].metadata[0].value.length;j++){
           _this.state.sortedJobs[response.data.jobs[i].metadata[0].value[j]].push(response.data.jobs[i]);
         }
       }
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
     //console.log(Object.keys(_this.state.sortedJobs).length);
     this.setState({sortedJobs: _this.state.sortedJobs});
     this.setState({loaded:true});
   },
   render:function(){
     var departments = this.state.sortedJobs;
     return(
       <div>
       {this.state.loaded ?
         <div className="row grid-12">
           {Object.keys(departments).map(function(label, department){
             //console.log(departments[label]);
             return <Department key={label} title={label} jobs={departments[label]}/>
           })}
         </div>
         :
         <div>Test</div>
       }
       </div>
     );
   }
 });



 const Department = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
      return{hidden:false, hasJobs:false};
    },
    componentWillMount:function(){
      const jobs = this.props.jobs;
      if(jobs.length>0){
        this.setState({hasJobs:true});
      }
    },
    componentDidMount:function(){
      console.log(this.state.hasJobs);
      console.log(this.props.jobs.length);
    },
    renderNormal:function(){
      return(
                <div className="grid-4 department-block" data-dep-filter={this.state.hidden} data-loc-filter="false" data-department={this.props.title}><h3 className="text-uppercase">{this.props.title}</h3>
                    <div className="posting-list margin-bottom">
            <h3 className="text-uppercase">{this.props.title}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
      )
    },
    renderEmpty:function(){
      return(
            <div className="grid-4 department-block" data-dep-filter={this.state.hidden} data-loc-filter="false" data-department={this.props.title}><h3 class="text-uppercase">{this.props.title}</h3>
                <div className="posting-list margin-bottom">
                    <div class="no-posts job-post">
                        <p><em>0 Current Openings</em></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      );
    },
    render: function(e){
      if (this.hasJobs) {
        return (
          this.renderNormal()
        )
      }else{
        return(
          this.renderEmpty()
        )
      }

    }
  });
```

In the Department:componentWillMount function I want to check the jobs array passed to it from the DepartmentContainer:render function and set the state on said Department to either hasJobs true/false

Comment: are you relying on some sort of data retrieval, ie api call? The `console.log` you are showing with 0 is what it was at at the time it was first called, once data eventually populated the array the console object updates as well.

Comment: I am calling the following component, passing a jobs area to the prop 'jobs'

return <Department key={label} title={label} jobs={departments[label]}/>

Inside the Department component I am able to log the actual array, but cannot get the array length

componentDidMount:function(){
      console.log(this.props.jobs.length);
    },

^^ does not work, but

componentDidMount:function(){
      console.log(this.props.jobs);
    },

Comment: Can you post your entire code sample for the component in question? preferably you edit your original post and add it at the bottom.

Comment: what happens if you do `componentWillUpdate: function() { console.log(this.props.jobs.length) }`

Comment: I am having similar issue. You found solution to it?

Answer (score 4):

@finalfreq has the right idea. This is an artifact of how the JavaScript console works (for Chrome at least). Values are generally only displayed/retrieved when you expand them, which can lead to some counter intuitive behavior. You must be adding elements to the array *after* you are logging it to the console.

Check it out:

I make an array and push something into it. Then I log it to console. Then I push a second element.

[image]

Now when I expand the previous logged Array, you'll see it now has the most up-to-date values. Except "`Array[1]`" doesn't update to "`Array[2]`"... and if you push another value into the array, the previously logged values won't change even if you collapse and expand them again.

[image]

The moral of the story is... don't rely on console.log *too* much hehe. But if you do, learn its quirks.